# Unloading data from Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

I have a table in Redshift with the following columns

```
id int,state varchar(50), name varchar(50),tsa varchar(50),countrycode varchar(50),country_id int
```

When I insert it into Redshift from AWS Lambda, it is expecting varchar's to be escaped like so -

```
cursor.execute('insert into test values (81,\'tn\',\'ic\',\'ICS\',\'US\',9)'))
```

I am unloading data from Redshift in the following ways -

**Method 1**

```
    unload ('select * from info')
    to 's3://Info/Load/' 
    iam_role 'arn:aws:iam:::role'
    addquotes
    ;
```

The output to S3 is

```
80|test|test1|test2S|US|9
```

**Method 2**

```
unload ('select * from info')
to 's3://Info/Load/' 
iam_role 'arn:aws:iam:::role'
;
```

The output to S3 is

```
"41"|"PA"|"PEN"|"Test"|"US"|"90"
```

How do I unload data from Redshift in the following format, so I can run inserts easily.

```
81,\'tn\',\'ic\',\'ICS\',\'US\',9
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use:

- `DELIMITER AS ','`
- `ADDQUOTES`
- `ESCAPE`

See: [UNLOAD documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html).

By the way, it is not recommended to insert data into Redshift via individual `INSERT` statements. You should bulk-loaded data from files using the `COPY` statement.